# How to Create a Simple Speaker Driver After LMC555 with Low Pass Filter

Tags: filter, driver, 555, low-pass

I created a very basic sound generator which ends in a LMC555 which plays a melody in the frequency range between 440Hz-880Hz. Now I struggle with the speaker driver. I would like to use very basic components like transistors and MOSFETs and no sophisticated IC.

The current circuit looks like this. I omitted the whole melody generating part. It uses MOSFETs to change the frequency of the LM555 as shown.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftQULW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The current solution is not ideal. But I struggle to bring the output signal from the LM555 into a signal which can be filtered using a simple RC low-pass filter so it can be used to be amplified using a transistor, or even be suitable to as input for an amplifier.

I looked through many examples, but they usually just connect the speaker directly to the LM555 without transforming the signal first. So the output will be still a very extreme square wave.

How could I implement a driver like this?

Comment: If I wanted a sine wave I'd start with an XR2206 not a 555, but that's not going to work from 3V

Comment: Take your output from the top end of c2 and you get one stage of low-pass filtering for free (also the amplitude here is not frequency dependant).  you will need an amplifier.

Comment: @Jasen If I connect anything to the frequency defining parts of the 555, this will change the frequency of the tones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgBf07.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Green box: addition of a DC-blocking (decoupling) capacitor to the output to drive the speaker safely. Orange box: addition of line-level output to drive an audio amplifier.*

First, lets fix the existing circuit. Loudspeakers don't like DC. It biases the operation to one side of the suspension's neutral point. They prefer AC. Addition of a decoupling capacitor will fix the DC part. You'll have to experiment with R5 but anything up to 20 Ω should work. That should get you a reasonable tone.

To connect to an amplifier add the components in the orange box. This will reduce the output voltage by a factor of about 10. Adjust the resistors if you want more. By adding capacitance in parallel with R7 you can attenuate high frequencies (which has the effect of rounding off the corners of the square-waves).

Comment: If you use an inductor for the green box resistor things will be more efficient .The DCR should be small compared to 8 ohm .The reactance should be high compared to 8 ohm .You could start with a 5mH car radio choke .

Comment: where is the low-pass filter requested in the text?  stick some chewing-gum to the speaker cone?

Comment: Indeed, the actual question isn't answered here.

Comment: @Jasen: Low-pass filter is covered in the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I thought I covered both the question in the title (green box in schematic) and "_... or even be suitable to as input for an amplifier._" (orange box in schematic) along with the filter. I've learned to re-read the questions after I write and answer and before I hit the "post" button. What did I miss?

Comment: @Transistor Your answer did not solved the low pass filter for the speaker, but it was the right direction so I could fix all remaining problems. The simple DC to AC conversion with the decoupling capacitor for the speaker was very useful.

Comment: Good. I didn't think it was worth pursuing the direct speaker drive too much if you were going to use an amplifier. Thanks for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build a linear audio amplifier (unless you want to get into class D topologies). Here is roughly the kind of thing you could use, from [this](http://www.seekic.com/circuit_diagram/Amplifier_Circuit/index32.html) source:

[image]

It's just a random circuit from the internet so surely check that it is correct, but the basic approach looks sound. Or just use a (very old, not especially sophisticated) IC such as the [LM386](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf), which is of similar vintage to the 555.

[image]

You will see some similarities to the discrete circuit, including the bias network for the output transistors:

[image]

It's a bit different, partly because a current mirror is better than a resistor (and easy in IC form) and partly because PNP transistors tend not be very good on this kind of IC- they're lateral type and suffer from inferior gain.

Comment: My problem here is that the whole circuit is made for 3V voltage. It is driven by two AA batteries. I own some "vintage" :-) LM386, even with DIL packages, but the minimal voltage is 3V.

Comment: Maybe try some simulations with the top circuit. It should operate to a bit lower voltage than the LM386.

Comment: @Flovdis - What kind of speaker are you driving, and what sort of fidelity are you asking for. On the matter of fidelity, be aware that a pure sine tone is enormously annoying to listen to, so you might do better not filtering.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Pure sine waves are literally monotonous.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany "There was a young man named Fife/Whose marriage was ruined for life..."

Answer (score 0):

You've got excellent discussions, already. It's the one-sided driver aspect that was killing you. So you have some things to think about.

You mention, correctly I see, that you are operating off of \$3V\$. If you are open to the idea of yet another IC, you might consider some of the ICs used for those very cheap PC speaker systems. The TDA8551 comes to mind. They will happily operate off of 3V. (\$2.7V\$ to \$5.5V\$.) These are bridge-tied types and sized to deliver about \$\frac{1}{2} W\$ when running on \$3V\$ into an \$8\Omega\$ load. Which is probably enough. They are cheap ($1) and readily available (mouser, etc.) You even get a fancy volume control feature, as well.

Just offering it as an alternative idea to consider. Not a replacement for understanding the problem you encountered. Besides, it is worth knowing about and understanding what "bridge-tied load" means. So this comment can also be educational, too.